# Formula / conditional formatting for cell value in MS Excel

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Here is my question?
I have an excel worksheet, where inputs are fed by me in the cells. I have a typical situation. When the input value is 0.0, it should show as **--** instead of **0**.
Say in cell B4, I enter a value 0.0, it should show "**--**". Neither **if** formula nor **conditional formatting** helps me here.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to use number formatting - the third part of it sets the formatting of a zero, e.g. `+0.00, -0.00, --` - but this no question about programming, but instead for Superuser

Comment: How? Format cell that contain value equal to "0", format number has no effect. I need this to be plain 'dash'.

Answer (score 1):

format cells -> Custom -> `#,##0.0 ; -#,##0.0 ; --`

Comment: Yes, this did the trick.